# Stateful RNN has wrong tensor shape in Keras Functional model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I defined a Keras functional model containing a block with a stateful LSTM, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python import keras


data = np.ones((1,2,3))

input_shape = data.shape  # batch size, step size, input size
output_units = 2

### input block ###
inputs = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=input_shape, name="inputs")


### model block with stateful RNN ###
dummy_inputs_1 = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=input_shape, name="dummy_inputs_1")
recurrent_1 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=input_shape[-1], batch_input_shape=input_shape,
                                return_sequences=True, stateful=True,
                                name="recurrent_1")(dummy_inputs_1)

dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(output_units, batch_input_shape=(
    input_shape[0], input_shape[-1], input_shape[1]),
                             name="dense_1")
output_1 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(dense_1, input_shape=input_shape, name="output_1")(recurrent_1)

model_1 = keras.models.Model(inputs=[dummy_inputs_1], outputs=[output_1], name="model_1")
model_1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer='Nadam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.predict(data) #works

### add model block to model ###
model_block = model_1(inputs)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[model_block], name="model")
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer='Nadam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.predict(data) #works

model.predict(data)  #fails
```

As written, the first `predict()` call (to the inner model block containing the stateful LSTM layer) works fine, but the second fails with this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../functional_stateful.py", line 38, in <module>
    model_1.predict(data)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1478, in predict
    self, x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 363, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 2897, in __call__
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1454, in __call__
    self._session._session, self._handle, args, status, None)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'inputs' with dtype float and shape [1,2,3]
     [[Node: inputs = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1,2,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

With `stateful=True` commented out in the LSTM definition, the whole thing runs fine. Does anyone know what's happening?

**Edit:**
Apparently just calling the stateful model block on another layer is enough to cause `predict()` for that block to fail (i.e. this code fails with the same error):

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python import keras

data = np.ones((1,2,3))

input_shape = data.shape  # batch size, step size, input size
output_units = 2

### input block ###
inputs = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=input_shape, name="inputs")


### sample model block with stateful RNN ###
dummy_inputs_1 = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=input_shape, name="dummy_inputs_1")
recurrent_1 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=input_shape[-1], batch_input_shape=input_shape,
                                return_sequences=True, stateful=True,
                                name="recurrent_1")(dummy_inputs_1)

model_1 = keras.models.Model(inputs=[dummy_inputs_1], outputs=[recurrent_1], name="model_1")
model_1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer='Nadam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

# ### add model block to model ###
model_block = model_1(inputs)

model_1.predict(data) #fails
```

**Edit 2:**
But apparently, adding a call to predict() for the stateful block *before* calling it on another block lets you still use it afterwards (i.e. the below runs fine):

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python import keras

data = np.ones((1,2,3))

input_shape = data.shape  # batch size, step size, input size
output_units = 2

### input block ###
inputs = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=input_shape, name="inputs")


### sample model block with stateful RNN ###
dummy_inputs_1 = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=input_shape, name="dummy_inputs_1")
recurrent_1 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=input_shape[-1], batch_input_shape=input_shape,
                                return_sequences=True, stateful=True,
                                name="recurrent_1")(dummy_inputs_1)

model_1 = keras.models.Model(inputs=[dummy_inputs_1], outputs=[recurrent_1], name="model_1")
model_1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer='Nadam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.predict(data) #works

# ### add model block to model ###
model_block = model_1(inputs)

model_1.predict(data) #works
```

Comment: github link to the same question here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10643

Comment: What is your keras/tensorflow version?

Comment: Tensorflow 1.9.0rc2

Comment: And keras? It seems pretty new... there were similar bugs with old versions, but this one is different then.... I think the problem is related to "how will it handle multiple inputs?" -- A stateful model should receive batches sequentially to work properly... if you start passing parallel batches, it will probably get confused as how to know what is the correct order...

Comment: It looks like the included version (from tensorflow.python.keras) is '2.1.6-tf'.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're suggesting about the issue, but is that something that would affect the nested model but not the internal block by itself?

Comment: If you were to use two inputs simultaneously into a stative=True RNN, it would not be able to properly keep track of the sequence, the states would be messed up. You should have two separate layers for two inputs so their states don't get mixed.

Comment: Where are the two parallel inputs here, I guess? Doesn't the `inputs` tensor flow sequentially into the `dummy_input_1` layer, since the `model_1` block was called on it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `stateful=True` RNNs are incompatible with multiple inputs.
(In your code, you have `dummy_inputs_1` and `inputs`. This will be called "multiple inbound nodes" by keras in many of its messages. Actually, you have two parallel branches there, one regarding the original `dummy_inputs_1`, another regarding the new `inputs`)

Why is that? A `stateful=True` layer is meant to receive "a sequence" (or many "parallel" sequences in a batch) which is split in groups of timesteps.

When it receives batch 2, it will interpret this as a sequel of batch 1 regarding the sequences time steps.

When you have two input tensors, how is the RNN supposed to interpret what continues what? You'd lose the consistency of a "continuous sequence". The layer only has "one tensor for states", it can't keep track of parallel tensors with this.

So, if you're going to use a stateful RNN with more than one input, I suggest you create copies of the layer. If you want them to share the same weights, this would probably require custom layers that get a common weight tensor.

Now, if your intention is to use this block once, you should probably use `model_1.input` and `model_1.output` instead of providing another input tensor.

Comment: I'll try using model.input instead. But, if the `inputs` tensor flows directly into `dummy_input_1`, why are they considered parallel branches?